# Anaconda Navigator Loading Issues on Ubuntu 18.10 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, anaconda

A Win/Linux dual boot machine w/ Anaconda 3 installed, recently upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10, is very sluggish in loading Anaconda Navigator. Sometimes it takes ~10+ minutes. This started about a week ago.

I updated conda and Anaconda; after the update, Navigator loaded quickly and "normally".  Then, after going back to Windows and then back into Ubuntu, it reverted to the previous behavior.  Navigator loads, but takes a long time.

I've tried most of the other tips on path, etc. from Stack Overflow, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is pretty rickety on all platforms. I've had this same experience on Windows and Mac OS. The whole anaconda app seems made by amateurs. Would recommend using `conda` from command line, and moving your operation to another virtual environment. `Docker` might work for you. You can set up a Docker server on your computer and it'll let you create virtual environments for your entire project, like Anaconda.

Comment: This response is like pulling up next to someone in a broken Buick on the side of the road and telling them they should get a Toyota.  Fine in the abstract, but about as useful as teats on a boar.

Comment: Your metaphor doesn't work in this context. He's already admitted his Buick wouldn't even drive off the lot. Go to a different dealer next door and get a working Toyota. They all buy lots next to each other anyway. There ya go, fixed your metaphor.

Comment: Not really, clearly stated there was some functionality but not ideal functionality.